# What additional paperwork would be needed to get from EAL4 vertification to EAL7?

Tags: common-criteria

If my product is currently at EAL4, what is the process to get to EAL7? What additional paperwork or requirements would I need to complete?

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to the kind of product, who the evaluation is doing and who should the evaluation accept at the end, i.e. there is no generic answer apart from [Wikipedia: EAL7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_Assurance_Level#EAL7:_Formally_Verified_Design_and_Tested). You better talk to the parties who did the EAL4 evaluation for you and already know lots of details of your product for how to achieve EAL7 with this specific product.

In general EAL7 is much harder too achieve than EAL4. It comes with requirements like formal verification which are simply not doable currently for more complex software systems.

Answer (score 0):

In general, outside of very narrow set of self-contained products (e.g. smartcards) EAL7 is not achievable on existing products due to formal design and analysis requirements.

Comment: Haven't you just repeated the first answer?

Comment: The key information I was trying to communicate that you can't get EAL7 for most products no matter what you do. It has to be a self-contained high-security product like a smartcard or HSM for this to be even feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can [read the definitions of the assurance levels](https://commoncriteriaportal.org/files/ccfiles/CCPART3V3.1R5.pdf). It'll tell you exactly what the deliverables are for each EAL. But that won't tell you how you might achieve these deliverables.

The general wisdom that I've heard about Common Criteria evaluation levels is that you can take any product with a decent security record, make minor changes to it, write a lot of documentation and possibly tests, and bring it up to EAL4. On the other hand, going past EAL5 requires a product that has been designed from the start for this kind of semi-formal or formal design. I've only worked on lower EALs, but it seems plausible to me.

Even at low EALs, it's hard to get through a certification on your own if you've never done it before. You're likely to need to engage a consultant who's used to Common Criteria. At high EALs, you'll definitely need a consultant who's used to higher EALs. Take the time to go through the product with the consultant. But the outcome is very likely to be that you can't go to EAL7 with an existing product.

If you want to achieve an EAL7 certification, you need significant in-house expertise with formal hardware and software design and verification, and you need a solid design from the ground up. Your existing product would only be a prototype for that.